# jquery/css: how to implement a wipe left animation on background-color of a div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-effects, css-transitions

Here's my css

```
#Slide {
    background: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 140px;
}
#Slide.Selected {
    background: #ff0;
}
```

I want that whenever I add/remove the class `Selected` to `#Slide`, the background-color property is animated by wiping in from left/wiping out to right. Normally, the background-color just appears and disappears. If this is not doable while using css class, is it possible by using jquery `.animate()` function? or may be css3 `transition` property?

Any suggestions somebody

Comment: I don't think you can animate the background color to slide with a css class. What you have to do is to have a div with the new desired color that slide in/out. The answer on this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633115/background-color-property-slide-up) has a fiddle to illustrate.

Comment: If you don't need to support ie you can also use gradient for background and animate background position - either using css transitions, or a plugin that extends jquery animate so that in can operate on background position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do a wipe animation on background color with either jQuery or CSS3 animations.

To get this visual effect, you have a couple options.  You can do a wipe transition on a whole separate element that is positioned behind your existing element such that it simulates the background.  Or, you may be able to use a background image of the desired color and size and animate the background position to simulate a wipe.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a wipe_left function I did, saw your question when I was looking for my own answer:

```
wipe_left($('.wipe-left'), $('.wipe-left').css('width'));

function wipe_left (elem, width) {
        elem.css('width', '0px');
        elem.css("left", width);
        elem.animate({
            width: width,
            left: '0px'
        }, 5000);
    }

<div class="wipe-left" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: lightblue; width: 300px; height: 200px;">
        &nbsp;
</div>
```

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/LostInDaJungle/da16gx9n/1/

Answer (score 0):

A smooth background wipe effect can be created using CSS pseudo-elements and transitions.

First inject a background pseudo-element into your main container. Then when a class is added to the container, use a transform to move that background out of the way.

```css
#slide:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  background: teal;
}

#slide.on:before {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```js
$("#slide").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
});
```

```css
#slide {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: salmon;
}

#slide .contents {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#slide:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  background: teal;
}

#slide.on:before {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slide">
  <div class="contents">Click me!</div>
</div>
```

A few small considerations:

- The container's rules should include `overflow: hidden` and `position: relative`.
- Pseudo-elements will stack on top of non-positioned content nodes, so any visible contents of the container will need to be wrapped in a second block element.

[Example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/joemaller/pen/LOdmVM?editors=0100)